# Transaction priority

Tags: bitcoind, transaction-fees, error, coin-age-priority

I'm testing some functionality on the testnet and I'm having problems with the transactions priority.

According to the [technical info](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_fees#Technical_info), a transaction that has not enough priority should have a fee of 0.00001 BTC/kb (1000 Satoshi), but when I try to broadcast my transaction using a RPC call to my local full node, I get an insufficient priority error:

```
{u'message': u'66: insufficient priority', u'code': -26}
```

For example, the following transaction has 3 inputs and 2 outputs:

```
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
```

what according to [bitcoinfees](http://bitcoinfees.com/) will have a size of:

```
148 * 3 + 34 * 2 + 10 = 522 bytes
```

and it also has a transaction fee of 0.00001 bitcoins, but trying to broadcast it will raise the error shown above.

Does anyone knows what could I've been doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Bitcoin Core is your full node running?  The minimum fees were different in earlier versions.

Comment: Bitcoin Core Daemon version v0.11.2.0-g7e27892

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe it could be because of bitcoin dust. Does any output of less than 0.01 BTC require a fee of 0.00001? I mean, if I'm building a transaction with three inputs, two of them of less than 0.01 BTC, and a total size of less than 1KB, would it need 2*0.00001 BTC because of the two small inputs?

Comment: At this point I think the best way to try to understand it might be to single-step the source code, either mentally or with a debugger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found what was wrong. It seems that [technical info](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_fees#Settings) is not up to date to the current Bitcoin Core version (0.11.2.0). Since version 0.11 (12 July 2015) the minimum relay fee is [5 times bigger](https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.11.0#transaction-flooding) (from 1000 Satoshi to 5000) so the transaction has not enough fees to be relayed.

[Here](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1260280.0) you could find a discussion about the topic.